# How to insert _ char after every Camel case char in a string in intellij using find/replace regex?

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

intellij has some nice tricks to find replace with regex,

I have this string in a file:

```
tryingToTurnToConstStandard
```

and I want to turn it to:

```
TRYING_TO_TURN_TO_CONST_STANDARD
```

I managed to turn it to

```
TRYINGTOTURNTOCONSTSTANDARD
```

By doing this:
[image]

Meaning I enabled the regex for find, and I am searching for char with length more then 1 by using the regex: \w+

To capture the result by wrapping it with round brackets

In the replace field I target the only group I have using $1
And wrap it with \U \E - the first for upper case and the second to end the upper case ( lower case is the same, just with \L )

But I can't find how to insert the '_' char and doing it all in a single find/replace, any ideas?

edit:
I need it for a general case, because I have multiple variables that I need to do it for, here are some more examples:

```
public static final String tryingToTurnToConstStandard = "";
public static final String thisIsAnotherExample = "";
public static final String backToTheFuture = "";
public static final String thisIsAVeryLongVariable = "";
```

Comment: Can you try this finding with this regex `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` and replace it with underscore?

Comment: Have you thought of doing 2 passes? First pass, regex to add underscore before the capital letter. Second pass, capitalize all letters.

Comment: Yaa, that what I am doing now, just wondered if that the only way or maybe intellij has some more useful magic in it.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

search: `([a-z]+)([A-Z])([a-z]*)`
replace: `\U$1_$2$3`

Comment: Almost, but it'll fail with short words

Comment: @ThomasAyoub can you give what do you have and what do you want ? (like before and after)? I understood you have only `tryingToTurnToConstStandard` in your file

Comment: @Kent that might work but I need to know the amount of groups you have, and I need something more general for a large file with lots of word combinations

Comment: @ohadedelstain your example is not generic enough. then change your example to one which can conver all your requirements

Comment: @ohadedelstain do **NOT** post screenshot! "before & after" in code block pls!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

Replace with `\U$1_$2`.

Comment: that might work but I need to know the amount of groups you have, and I need something more general for a large file with lots of word combinations